# Visio 2007 org chart ideas

Tags: wizard, visio, orgchart

I'm trying to use Visio 2007 Org Chart wizard to generate a Product Breakdown Structure using a .csv exported from MS Project.  The fields are:

- Name
- Parent Product
- Function
- Internal/External

There are several things I want to do but I'm struggling to find the guidance anywhere, or at least struggling to find the guidance written in a way that doesn't require you to already be a Visio expert (and therefore unlikely to need to ask in the first place) in order to understand it.

I've managed to get the wizard to use a modified master shape to represent Collective Grouping products, and use shape data to colour shapes based on the product's function. There are two other things I'd like to do.

1. Is it possible to get the wizard to use a custom shape for External product? For example, these products might sit at any level in the hierarchy but I want all External products to be rhomboids instead of rectangles and I want the wizard to do it rather than me manually changing them all afterwards.
2. I want to put all of the shapes with a particular function on it's own layer automatically rather than manually because the function's products will be scattered around the chart (it needs to be, grouping them all together won't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you make the question more concise?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks gents, will try super user instead.